# How do I add my Azure Sql Server Admin User to 'Sysadmin' Server Role?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm attempting to migrate a Sql Db from a local server to Azure using the new [Data Migration Assistant v2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595) ([announced here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/10/27/upgrade-with-data-migration-assistant-2-0-and-database-experimentation-assistant-preview/)).

It seems to have connected to my source *(a local SQL 2014 server, Windows Auth)* and destination *(Azure V12 SQL, server admin username and password)* servers correctly, but gives the following error when attempting to get to the 'Add Database' step.

> Provided credentials for target server
>   'fooserver.database.windows.net' have insufficient server-level
>   permissions to perform migration. The credentials used to connect to
>   the target server must be a member of the sysadmin server role.

How do I add my Azure Sql Server admin user to the 'sysadmin' server role? I couldn't see anything related to this in the Azure Portal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe that Data Migration Assistant is the right tool for the job. If you original database is Microsoft SQL one you could either use The Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Upgrade Advisor Preview or The Export Data Tier application wizard in SQL Server Management Studio. I have used both approaches many times and they work very well.

The following article is probably the best one our there that lists and explains all available options - [SQL Server database migration to SQL Database in the cloud](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate/).

Let me know if you have any questions.

**Update 1** - @Ted has contacted Microsoft and they have said that Data Migration Assistant does not support migrating to Azure at the moment. This scenario will be supported in a future version.

Comment: Thanks Milan, you're right that article is probably the most helpful information on achieving a premises Sql Server to Azure Sql migration out there at the moment. I had hope that the Data Migration Assistant would do it all for me, but after writing to MS themselves via the Feedback option in DMA, they said that it isn't actually capable of doing this at present, but will be at some point in the future.

Comment: @Ted, thanks for sharing what MS have said. This would be really helpful for other people that are struggling with it. I will add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Nov 2017 Update**

The [MS Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595) now absolutely **does** support migrating on premises SQL databases to Azure SQL, as well assessing your DB for compatibility, and providing / applying suggestions for fixes if required.