# Azure SQL Server Migration

Tags: sql-server, azure, migration

I'm trying to export data from a local sql server to a Azure SQL Server using the Data Migration Assistant
However the DMA is blocking setting up the upgrade saying that the account used to create the Azure DB does not have sufficient admin privileges to do so
There doesn't seem to be an SA account to go to on Azure and I was wondering if anyone had ideas that may shed light on this?

Comment: Are you trying to create .bacpac file?

Answer (score 0):

This [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361576/how-do-i-add-my-azure-sql-server-admin-user-to-sysadmin-server-role) seems relevant.

Ted and Milan were saying DMA did not support migration to azure sql server right now however as of April this year Microsoft [released](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Data-Exposed/Data-Migration-Assistant-Adding-SQL-Database) an updated DMA.

You should be at least owner in Access control (IAM) of the Azure SQL server.